# Using both standard and significant-Change Location Service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I like to extend my app which is using Standard Location Service with the capability to notice the app when an Location change happend even when the app is not running or in Background.

Apple proposes for this the use of the significant-Change Location Service, which would be ok to save battery power and the accuracy would be fine for me.

But is it possible to use both the standard and significant-Change Location Service together in one Project ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to implement this with the help of the Apple Developer Forums. I did the following:

**Specify location background mode

    Use an NSTimer in the background by using

      UIApplication:beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:**
In case n is smaller than  **UIApplication:backgroundTimeRemaining** ,it does works just fine, in case n is larger, the location manager should be enabled (and disabled) again before there is no time remaining to avoid the background task being killed.
This does work since location is one of the three allowed types of background execution.

**Note: Dont loose time by testing this in the simulator where it doesn't work, works fine on my phone**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but seems to complicated for what i like to achive, i just like to use built in significant-Change Location Service for backgound Tasks and the Standard Location Service when the app is running.

Comment: please let me know if  you are saying that when you close your app or it is running in background then updated location is required ?

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/ 
check this tutorial

Comment: Yes update location is required when running in backgound or app is closed, thats what significant Change Location Service offers out of the box.

Comment: have you checked above link?